# Missing classes in activity_main.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm completely new to Kotlin and want to learn how to code basic Android apps.
So I wanted to follow some tutorials but after starting a new project with the 'Empty Activity' template in Android Studio the entire code in the activity_main.xml turns red.
It says:

```
Class referenced in the layout file, androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout, was not found in the project or the libraries
```

I have no idea how to fix this. The solutions I found online did not help at all.

I tried 'Invalidate Caches / Restart',

I made sure it's
`androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` in the .xml and not `androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout`

In the build.gradle(project) is `google()` under `repositories` and

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
```

is in the build.gradle(:app)

I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: I doubt you need `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'` as you already have `implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'`

Comment: I tried it again without the 'com.android.support ...' and nothing changed. Also when I'm in the 'Design' tab of the activity_main.xml the TextView "Hello World!" in the component tree has no attributes or whatsoever.

Comment: After removing `implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'` try to 'Invalidate Caches / Restart'.

Comment: Unfortunately it stays red.

Comment: can you try adding this to gradle.properties ->

android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true

Comment: I opened gradle.properties and both were already there, but they are red underlined...

Comment: What version of Android Studio do you have? Help -> About.

Comment: I have Android Studio 4.1.1. I never had this software before as far as I know, so I basically just downloaded the software, created a new project like in the tutorial I wanted to follow and ran in those issues when I wanted to change("access"?) the attributes of something in the "Component Tree"

Answer (score 1):

you can use th androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Comment: You can go through here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx